# How do we know that there is a smooth function that is constant on two disjoint non-empty compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset.$ Prove that there is a smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with values ranging (inclusively) between 0 and 1 and satisfying $f|_A=0,$ $f|_B=1$.

One way to approach this problem is by finding a satisfactory $f$ that is continuous, then smoothing it via convolution. For example, we could define $f(x)=\frac{\text{min}(\text{dist}(x,A),\text{dist}(x,B))}{\text{dist}(A,B)}$ for a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This function is continuous because taking the minimum of continuous functions is continuous, as is taking the quotient of continuous functions. However, at this point, I'm lost on how to make it smooth.

I'm told there is also a way to show this using partitions of unity. I would very much like to understand this method as well, but I'm unsure even about where to start. I believe that this method also requires a step where we take a smooth approximation of our "first attempt" function.

I think I am missing some of the analytic background to answer this question. References to/explanations of relevant concepts from analysis would be helpful (especially why they are necessary, and what they guarantee).

Comment: Partitions of unity provide an alternative proof. As for approximation, have you heard about convolutions?

Comment: You can also use the result that every closed subset is the zero set of a smooth function.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that convolutions are how we "make our continuous function smooth." But the explicit details of this are what I'm asking about. For example, how do we know that the convolution preserves the desired properties? If the question seems basic, it's because it is; e.g., even a reference to a good source for learning about convolutions in this context would be helpful.

Comment: Please read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) Wikipedia article. If the answer to your question is still unclear, let me know (you have to ping me) and I will write an answer.

Comment: Evans measure theory and fine properties of functions is nice for convolutions

Comment: Does a [smooth bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) fulfill what you are asking for? something like $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,\quad x=0;\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 1;\\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(-\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ as example?